# JQuery "Get" not getting absolute path in MVC4

Tags: jquery, get, asp.net-mvc-4

On my dev box the URL to my site is "http://localhost:portname/home" and when I click on the "Hello " on the top right side after logging in, the path it takes me to is "localhost:­/­Account/­GetTabContent/tab1"

using the following jQuery code:

```
var url = "/Account/GetTabContent/tab1";
var targetDiv = $('#div1');
$.get(url, null, function (result) {
  $(targetDiv).html(result);
});
```

This works fine on my box.  However when we deploy it to our test server the actual website's path is:

```
http://server name/website folder/home
```

Now when I click on the Name after logging in it still takes me to

```
http://server name/Account/GetTabContent/tab1
```

and I get a 404 error.  How do I force it to go to

```
http://server name/website folder/GetTabContent/tab1
```

I hope my question makes sense. Please let me know if it doesnt and I will clarify

*******EDIT************

ok we fixed the problem by changing the following code (removed the controller name from the url, wonder how this will be when calling another controller's action)

```
**var url = "GetTabContent/tab1";**
var targetDiv = $('#div1');
$.get(url, null, function (result) {
$(targetDiv).html(result);
});
```

Comment: This sounds like an IIS problem, in that you probably need to be running the app under a virtual directory for `<website folder>`.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. <website folder> is a virtual directory under <DefaultWebSite>

Answer (score 1):

Generally I would recommend to set the path using the Url Helpers, so in your code above do this instead:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("GetTabContent", "Account", new { id = "tab1" })';
var targetDiv = $('#div1');
$.get(url, null, function (result) {
  $(targetDiv).html(result);
});
```

In places where urls are accepted (such as script tags etc), specify your urls with the tilde, so e.g.:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/foo.js"></script>
```

(this presume MVC 4, but since that is tagged I figured this seems fair :))

instead of specifying relative or worse absolute paths to a location that you may want to change at deployment time.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on a lot of frameworks my solution is to set the action of the form to where i want it to go as the mvc usually uses something similar to `echo Form:open('action');` which kicks out an absolute path bear in mind this is on a php framework but id assume asp ones offer something similar so with my jquery i use

```
$.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function and so on
```